# Grafana plugin node project won't sync with node_module in dev mode

Tags: plugins, node-modules, grafana

I'm having an issue trying to link a grafana plugin I'm working on.
This plugin use a node module that I'm also modifying (I have to modify both of them), but everytime I add the plugin to grafana I see the the node_module is not in sync and keeps loading the original version. The plugin change on the other hand are all being updated acordingly, but not the other modeule under node_module.

If someone have an idea I would really appreciate it, I have a feeling is simple. I just can't figure it out.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be because I was running grafana in docker and linking my plugin to the grafana container with a volume, so the dependencies were never found and they were downloaded.

Installing grafana locally and adding the the other module via
`npm install --save <my_dev_module>` resolved it.